# Map Property to User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` and have added a Property to it. But i want the Property to be added to the `Properties Window` whenever my `UserControl` is added to a form.

This is what i used to add the property

```
Image img;
public Image SetImage 
{
    get { return img; }
    set { img = value; }
}
```

This works fine but the problem is that whenever a user wants to call this property, the user will have to call the class of the user control like

```
MyControl ctrl = new MyControl();
ctrl.Image = Image.FromFile("/*Path to Image*/");
```

but this will change all that property for all the Controls that have been added to that form but what i need is to map it to the UserControl so that whenever the user want to call it, the user will call it like

```
MyControl1.Image = Image.FromFile("/*Path to Image*/");
```

or

```
MyControl2.Image = Image.FromFile("/*Path to Image*/");
```

Pls how do i acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `[Browsable(true)]` tag (which is in `System.ComponentModel`namespace inside `System.dll`) to your desired property of your user control class:

```
public class YourUserControl
{
    ....
    ....
    [Browsable(true)]
    public Image SetImage 
    {
        get { return img; }
        set { img = value; }
    }
}
```